# Hover a segment through CSS on Visual composer

Tags: html, css, hover, visual-composer

Hi i just want to ask regarding my issue. I'm stucked on these.

I wanted to hover a segment on my homepage using CSS but unfortunately im using a Visual composer.

What i want is that when someone hover on the segment the icon and all the text there will highlight. [See image for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A71cn.jpg)

I used these code on CSS for now

```
a.specialeffects:hover, h2.specialeffects:hover { color: #fa9928; }
.specialeffects { color: #fff; }
```

However the issue is that only the one that are tagged by the class="specialeffects" are hovering and they are not hovering at the same time.

What i want is that i need the whole area to be highlighted whenever i hover to that area. Can anyone suggest on how i can do it? Its either through CSS or Visual Composer.  Thank you!

Comment: Could you post your html and css for that section?

Comment: Here's the link of the HTML and CSS. For the html i've got only that portion and for CSS its the whole css. Since im using a purchased template. Its quite hard to pinpoint that area.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cckbnnjpnerochg/css.txt?dl=0
https://www.dropbox.com/s/adml8o438zgzbp7/html.txt?dl=0

Comment: I can't find the HTML code...?